# NTP client connection timeout

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct addrinfo hints,*res;
    char hostname[12],timedata[200];
    
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(argv[1],"123",&hints,&res);
    int socketfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    
    struct sockaddr_in *foo=(struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
    printf("connecting to server: %s\n",inet_ntoa(foo->sin_addr));

    if(connect(socketfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)==-1){
        perror("connect error");return -1;}
    printf("connected to server\n");

    recv(socketfd,timedata,sizeof timedata,0);
    printf("%s\n",timedata);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code for a ntp client that recieves the daytime message from ntp server

but when i run it `./ntpclient time.google.com` i get `connect error:Connection timed out`
i have tried other servers as well same problem

Comment: It is quite unusual to connect to an NTP server using TCP. Most servers only support UDP. So I think `SOCK_DGRAM` makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an NTP client or a daytime client? Why would you receive a daytime message from an NTP server?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As you can see he connects to port `123`. The question says "NTP". And `time.google.com` is an NTP server. I don't understand where you got `daytime` from.

Comment: Also, don't use the `AI_PASSIVE` flag when creating a socket to `connect()` to a server, only when creating a socket to `listen()` for connections.

Comment: Aside: Coudl repleace `struct addrinfo hints, ...  memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);` with `struct addrinfo hints = { 0 };`

Comment: @Cheatah Two places. One, he says, "this is my code for a ntp client that recieves the **daytime** message from ntp server". Two, his code would be correct (other than the port) if he was speaking to a daytime server. NTP, among other things, requires sending a query to get a response. He says he expected to receive a daytime message and his code looks like it reflects that expectation.

Comment: Port 123 is NTP, but NTP rides on UDP, not TCP.  Also, where is the NTP pkt built here--I do not see it? Need to have root access to use this port AFAIK.